# Which SMART settings to watch for in SpeedFan?

Tags: hard-drive, monitoring, smart, speedfan

Unless there's a better solution, I'd like to use [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) to watch hard disks on a host.

However, it offers quite a lot of settings in its Configure > Events > If section, such as Raw Read Error Rate, Spin Up Time, Start/Stop Count, etc.

[image]

Which significant events should I watch for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reallocated sector count, is one of the better things to observe , to tell if bad things are happening to the platter and data.  If I saw only one thing, that would be it.  A few of these over years is nothing, a sudden quantity of reallocated sectors could mean a head crash, or something bad has happened , or the platter and head are having problems, if they keep building up more and more, then something is wrong , and it is likely to need replacement.  Then the person would want to secure thier data even more than before (with proper backups).

A small quantity of reallocations then stabilising with no more added continually, could define a lesser problem that might not be a big problem.